# Bad Request,But I dont know whats happened

Tags: google-fit

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdGIc.png)

Hello. I want to sync the data to googlefit, But it's Bad request, please help me.

```
{
 "error": {
 "code": 400,
 "message": "unexpected FpVal: com.google.step_count.delta [2021-03-30T03:44:33.824Z - 2021-03-30T03:44:41.824Z] [70.0] raw:com.google.step_count.delta:230168028193",
 "errors": [
   {   
   "message": "unexpected FpVal: com.google.step_count.delta [2021-03-30T03:44:33.824Z - 2021-03-30T03:44:41.824Z] [70.0] raw:com.google.step_count.delta:230168028193",
   "domain": "global",
   "reason": "invalidArgument"
   }   
 ],
 "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
 }
}
```

Comment: "{\n  \"error\": {\n    \"code\": 400,\n    \"message\": \"unexpected FpVal: com.google.step_count.delta [2021-03-30T03:44:33.824Z - 2021-03-30T03:44:41.824Z] [70.0] raw:com.google.step_count.delta:230168028193\",\n    \"errors\": [\n      {\n        \"message\": \"unexpected FpVal: com.google.step_count.delta [2021-03-30T03:44:33.824Z - 2021-03-30T03:44:41.824Z] [70.0] raw:com.google.step_count.delta:230168028193\",\n        \"domain\": \"global\",\n        \"reason\": \"invalidArgument\"\n      }\n    ],\n    \"status\": \"INVALID_ARGUMENT\"\n  }\n}\n","statusCode":"400"}

Answer (score 0):

`com.google.step_count.delta` [has one field](https://developers.google.com/fit/datatypes/activity#step_count_delta), and it's an integer - because how can you take a fractional step?

Pass the step count as an integer, not a floating point value.